# How can I cache php generated files on CloudFlare?

Tags: php, mime-types, cloudflare

I want to add to the cloudflare cache jpg and pdf files generated from php pages, with urls in the form of «index.php?file=hola.pdf».
The files generated are static and everytime the same, but I think there are not being cached because of the php filename extension.

What can I do? What do you suggest?
Thanks and greets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Use PageRules to extend the caching](http://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-pagerules-advanced-caching) to include php and other files.

Notes: We don't cache by MIME type. The default configuration for the CDN caches [these static content types](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-What-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content-) by default.